# how to convert mongodb fields to subdocument fields?

Tags: mongodb

sorry it may be silly question, mongodb contains thousands of documents .

hard to be changed manually
original format

```
{"name" : "aaaa",
 "price" : 111,
 "ing1" : "abcd",
"ing1Conc" : 50 ,
 "ing2" : "wxyz",
"ing2conc": 100}
```

needed to be converted to

```
{"name" : "aaaa",
 "price" : 111,
 "content":[
    { "ing1" : "abcd", "ing1Conc" : 50},
    { "ing2" : "wxyz", "ing2conc": 100}
  ]
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you have **always** `ing1`,`ing1Conc`, `ing2`,`ing2Conc` or are they more (i.e. `ing3`,`ing3Conc`, `ing4`,`ing4Conc`, etc.)

Comment: may be 1 ingredient or upto 10 ingredients each contain name and concentration fields

Comment: What about the mixed cases `ing1Conc` and `ing2conc`? Is it on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial solution would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      price: 1,
      content: [
        { ing1: "$ing1", ing1Conc: "$ing1Conc" },
        { ing2: "$ing1", ing2conc: "$ing2conc" }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

A more generic solution would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggrega
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      price: 1,
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
          cond: { $regexMatch: { input: "$$this.k", regex: "^ing\\d+" } }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  { $set: { i: { $regexFind: { input: "$data.k", regex: "\\d+" } } } },
  { $set: { i: "$i.match" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name",
        price: "$price",
        i: "$i"
      },
      content: { $push: "$data" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "_id.i": 1 } },      
  { $set: { content: { $arrayToObject: "$content" } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { name: "$_id.name", price: "$_id.price" },
      content: { $push: "$content" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT", "$_id" ] } } },
  { $unset: "_id" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P4U5nD561AH)

However, I think this structure is still bad. I would suggest something like

```
content: { 
   ing: [ "abcd", "wxyz"], 
   conc: [ 50, 100 ]
}
content: [ 
  { ing: "abcd", conc: 50 }, 
  { ing: "wxyz", conc :100 }
]
content: [ 
  { idx: 1, ing: "abcd", conc: 50 }, 
  { idx: 2, ing: "wxyz", conc: 100 }
]
```